# How to call api when change value in vue multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to call api when there is a change value event in vue multiselect?
i want change value in multiselect , call api and show in console. The following is my code.

```
<template>
    <div>

        <multiselect v-model="value" placeholder="Select Your Currency" label="title" track-by="title" :options="options" :option-height="10"  :show-labels="false">
            <template slot="singleLabel" slot-scope="props"><img class="option__image"  :src="props.option.img" alt="No Man’s Sky"><span class="option__desc"><span class="option__title">{{ props.option.title }}</span></span></template>
            <template slot="option" slot-scope="props"><img class="option__image" :src="props.option.img" alt="No Man’s Sky">
                <div class="option__desc"><span class="option__title" :id="props.option.id">{{ props.option.title }}</span><span class="option__small">{{ props.option.desc }}</span></div>
            </template>
        </multiselect>

         </div>
         </template>

          <script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
    Vue.component('multiselect', Multiselect);

    export default {
        props: ['options'],
        components: {
            Multiselect
        },
        data () {
            return {
                value: { title: 'Bitcoin', img: 'https://coinnik.com/uploads/crypto- 
           logos/06fa2ab3d5a0f1d60e7d236aeccd6c6a.png' },

            }
        },
        methods: {

           }
        }
      </script>
```

app.js

```
    methods: {
        stepChanged(step) {
            this.currentstep = step;
        },
        apiCalc(){
            let self = this;

            axios.get('/ajax-calculation?includes=direction,direction.receiveCurrency&send_currency=2').then((response) => {
                self.calcApi = response.data;
                console.log('api:',self.calcApi.currency_id);
                // self.calcApi.currency_id;


            })
        }
    },
    components:{
        'multiselect': Multiselect
    },

    created() {
        this.apiCalc();
        },
      });
```

html

```
     <div class="col-md-12 mb-2">
<multiselect                                                                        :options="[                                                                                 { title: 'Tether', img: 'https://coinnik.com/uploads/crypto-logos/006fe133d48ea7cd45cf8ccb8cb7ec42.png' },
{ title: 'value', img: 'https://coinnik.com/uploads/crypto-logos/006fe133d48ea7cd45cf8ccb8cb7ec42.png' }]">
</multiselect>
</div>
```

How to define a method that I use when changing item then call api and show inside the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the deep watch on the value variable.

```
watch: {
  'value': {
    handler: function (after, before) {
      this.apiCalc();
    },
    deep: true
  },

},
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first, you can use the `@input` event to recognize when something has been picked, like so:

```html
<multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" @input="doApi" multiple></multiselect>
```

Then in doApi, you can check the current value.

```js
doApi() {
    console.log(this.value);
}
```

The value of `this.value` will be an array of what you have picked. You can pass these to your API. Full codepen here: https://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/gOOjjrb?editors=1111

Comment: im using multiselect , please help me to fix this chalenge

Comment: I apologize - when I saw "multiselect" I assumed a regular HTML multiselect.

Comment: Adding a new answer now - will be rushed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `@select` event? Vue Multiselect's documentation includes several events you can try, check it out here: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events

So try

```
<multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" @select="actionToExecute" multiple></multiselect>
```

And then define that in your methods. I'm currently using vue multiselect too so let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I had initially suggested that too, but if you do that, you don't get an update when an item is removed. I believe "input" is better (as I used in my answer).

Comment: im defined multiselect component in another file name multiselect.vue , and im want use this component in app.js and call api . then change value calling api in app.js show in console